# where can I find libstdc++.so.6 with support for GLIBCXX_3.4.21

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I try to install pandas with berryconda and the 'import pandas as pd' in python return me this error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/pi/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so).
```

OS is an up-to-date Jessie.
Use of berryconda is due to the very old release of pandas in Jessie repository.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1:

After following the direction on pandas' GitHub [issues page](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21929) which states:

> I confirmed that with pandas==0.22, there is no problem.

I tried this and success!

At the time of this answer, Miniconda on RasPi only supports up to Py3.6, so stepping back to 0.22.0 from 0.23.4, wasn't a huge issue (to me).

#### Option 2:

If you don't want to rollback the version of pandas, I found [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/764572/625092) very helpful.  I reinstalled pandas 0.23.4 and followed these instructions and all is well!

Basically:

- Find a later `libstdc++.so.6.x.x` file
- Copy it to `/usr/lib/arm-linux/gnueabihf`
- Create a symlink to `libstdc++.so.6`

In my case, I found a later version on a RasPi4, and copied it onto the Jessie box.